# "How to ask a good question" - not enough meta! especially in "Be on-topic"

Tags: discussion, meta, help-center

Just look at "Be on-topic" in ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask):

> Our community is defined by a specific set of topics that you [can view in the help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)...

Great; nothing wrong there.

> please stick to those topics and [avoid asking for opinions or open-ended discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Wut.... hey, we're on Meta. That's not applicable there! And neither is this phrase from the above link:

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here

That's wrong too. Not enough Meta!

> If your question is about the site itself, ask on our [meta-discussion site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Infinite recusion, eh... I'm already there... or was it going to say meta.meta?

Of course, this article seems to be taken from non-meta sites, but *hey* again.

Comment: Meta sites and main sites don't have separate help centers.  The help center links for both sites go to the same place.  It's literally the exact same URL, not just the same content.

Comment: That's okay, users don't read anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with this question; the help pages are still poorly worded seven years later. (One comment notes that "Meta sites and main sites don't have separate help centers", but that doesn't really apply here since MSE doesn't have a corresponding main site. (SE in general certainly shouldn't be considered MSE's "main site".))

Specifically, this sentence:

> If your question is about the site itself, ask on our meta-discussion site.

should simply be deleted.

The last paragraph of https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask should also be deleted:

> If your question is about the site itself, please don't ask it here. Visit our meta-discussion site, where you can talk about things like what questions are appropriate, what tags should be used, suggest a feature, point out a bug, or generally discuss how this site works.

I realize that this might not be a very high priority, but it shouldn't be left to fester for so many years, especially when it might easily confuse new users who don't fully understand what a meta site is and look to the help pages for guidance.

Comment: "If your question is about the site itself, please don't ask it here. Instead, ask it... well, here" :-D